# Do staitic Global Variable of Java Change there value when used in a function without returning?

Tags: java, arrays, static, global-variables

```
private static char[][] grid= new char[10][10];

private static void setHorizontal(String[] words, int i, int r, int c, boolean[] cross) {
    for (int j = c; j < (c+words[i].length()); j++) {
        if (grid[r][j] != '-'){
            cross[j-c]= false;
        }
        grid[r][j] = words[i].charAt(j-c);
    }
}
```

Will the value of grid change in the program or not??

Answer (score 0):

`grid[r][j] = words[i].charAt(j-c);` modified the values inside the `grid` array of arrays, the fact that the `setHorizontal` method is `void` does **not** matter; and the answer to your question is **yes** and **no**. The reference to `grid` does not appear to change (but another method could change it, since it is not `final`), and the values contained in the arrays of `grid` certainly do change when `setHorizontal` is invoked.